# Make html append variable with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, append

I have a textarea with a button, the content of this textarea inserts in a `<p>` when i click submit button, but when i click submit 2 or more times with another text in the textarea, the new text REPLACES old text in the older `<p>` makes before. I don't want to do this, i want to make new p with the new text of textarea without replacing the old text in the old p tags with the new text. Each p  inserts in a carrousel, but it's doesn't matter.

This is my code:

The initial p:

```
<div class="jcarouselbtext"  data-jcarousel="true">
  <ul class="popupbtext">
    <li><p class="info1">oLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The textarea with the button:

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
  <input type="button" id="getvalue" value="Enviar texto" class="demobutton">
```

The javascript code:

```
$(function () {
  $('#getvalue').click(function(){
    var textarea_value = $('#textarea').val();
    $('.show-textarea-value').html(textarea_value);
    var $btext = $('.popupbtext');
    var template = $('#template3').html();
    $btext.append(template);
    $('.jcarouselbtext').jcarousel('reload', {
    animation: 'slow'
  });
}); 

});
```

The script template for the new p tags:

```
<script id="template3" type="text/template">
  <li><p  class="info1 show-textarea-value"></p></li>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

[Here's a fiddle with what I think you're looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/X4fDN/11/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#getvalue').click(function(){
        // Get the text area value
        var textarea_value = $('#textarea').val();

        // Get a jQuery object of the template html
        var templateHolder = $($('#template3').html());

        // Put the text area text inside of the template's <p> tag 
        // Use .html() to overwrite the old content with the new 
        // content every time
        templateHolder.find('p').html(textarea_value);

        // Get a reference to the <ul> element
        var $btext = $('.popupbtext');

        // Add the template (with text area text) to the <ul> element
        $btext.append(templateHolder);

        // Commented out because it was throwing errors.  
        // Left in because it was part of original fiddle
        //$('.jcarouselbtext').jcarousel('reload', {
        //    animation: 'slow'
        //});
    }); 
});
```

*I commented out the jCarousel code because it was throwing errors.

**Original Answer**

Use append() instead of html()

Change

```
$('.show-textarea-value').html(textarea_value);
```

to

```
$('.show-textarea-value').append(textarea_value);
```

Comment: Okay this not replace the old with the new text, but ADD the new text to the OLD text, i only want to make a new p, without touching the old tags.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle/plunkr for it?  I'm a little confused with what you're asking now.

Comment: I maked this but i don't know why this don't work: http://jsfiddle.net/X4fDN/8/ When you write text in the textarea and click send it must to make new li with the text that you have entered in the textarea.

Comment: I think that your answer it's can be valid if my ids are not the same, if when i click the submit button if creates a new id, for example, newid1, click again and newid2... if could be work, but i don't know how to do, check this fiddle, i want to apply it to my code: http://jsfiddle.net/QaB76/

Comment: I updated my answer.  I hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yeah it worked like a charm!! I need another variant, how can do the same but instead of a textarea, an input text with title and another input with description? Thanks.